# Mult-level Drill Up

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using highcharts with a pie format. Initial load shows 2 slices. Clicking on one of the slices drops you down to a county distribution pie. You can then use the `drillUpButton` to get back to initial chart. The second slice is a bit different. When you click on it you are presented with a new pie chart showing the states that were not in the first-pie's state slice. Clicking on these state slices gives you the county level breakdown for that state. Clicking on the `drillUpButton` brings you back to the 2nd tier pie with all the states. Clicking on the `drillUpButton` again to get to the initial chart does not work and I am given this error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined

There are really two issues here:

- The 3rd tier `drillUpButton` text is not valid (seems like I need to
  add an `id` to my all state series).
- The drill up to the initial load chart does not work after going down
  3 levels. If I just click once to the state breakdown and click back
  it works. But if I click into state breakdown and then into county
  breakdown it fails.

Chart [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/wRuW7/).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a possibly bug, reported here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2911